# SalesForce - Packaging Button Overrides

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

As per this (closed) discussion:

http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrpJ

The Spring '10 Release of SalesForce is supposed to allow the packaging of Standard Button Overrides.

In my case, it's the "New" Opportunity button I'm overriding that loads a custom "Opportunities" Visual Force Page. Everything works exactly how I want it in my Dev environment.

However, my SalesForce "expert" is telling me that, despite what the Spring '10 Release Notes say, Standard Button Overrides can NOT be packaged and automatically installed when an org installs our app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Spring 10 Release notes - [Packageable Standard Action Overrides](http://na2.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_spring10_release_notes.pdf#rn_164_platform_minors__SAOPackage)

> Standard action overrides on buttons and links are now packageable for
>   custom objects. Developers can also create action overrides using the
>   Metadata API. Through this, it's possible to include a custom UI with
>   your apps. **Subscribers can accept these overrides in an installed
>   package, create their own, or revert to the standard Salesforce.com
>   behavior.**

However, in [Considerations for Overriding Standard Buttons](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/links_override_considerations.htm) it says:

> You cannot add button overrides to a Force.com AppExchange package.

Also, when adding components to the managed package there is no Component Type that will let you select the standard button overrides.

You can add your Custom Visualforce page to the package, but it will need to be manually configured as the override in the target Organization.

Comment: Yes, SalesForce Support has confirmed that this is not possible. Their response:

_After investigating your inquiry it appears that you cannot add button overrides to a force.com Appexchange package. The user would need to install the package and manually override the buttons. In most cases partners provide an instructions guide to users after installation for this type of setup._

However, I'm looking to see if a CSS hack is possible, where I add a Custom Button with my desired functionality, then use a CSS override to hide the original (default) "New" button.